# Woocommerce Checkout text not showing into page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, styles

Hi i have one weird issue that dont have seen before. Work on small project, and have woocommerce checkout page where text is exist but its not visible at all.
 Problem bellow:

[image]

I tryed to insert:

```
color:#000;
```

to some elements but i didnt noticed any changes.. This problem is happening only when add [product](https://huskypalace.com/product/siberian-husky-adoption-deposit/) to checkout. Someone tip or help what to change or update to take this page functional? Thanks

Comment: If you set the margin-left to 0px in .product-info you can see the text appear.  Looks like there is an issue with your template though all the formatting seem corrupted.

Comment: Can you post as answer, so i can accept your answer as verified?

Comment: Yes sure, thanks for the points Rob :)

Comment: Can you help me with total and subtotal text? still not shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the margin-left to 0px in .product-info you can see the text appear. Looks like there is an issue with your template though all the formatting seem corrupted.